# diagnose 404 for asp net POST request

Tags: asp.net, iis

How can i diagnose the 404 errors on my asp.net application.
It seems in iis logs that GET request to my *.aspx page return success ( code 200)
The POST request to same page returns a 404 error , not able to diagnose why.

Is there a seperate setting to allow POST request to this page or some where in the application.

**Edit #1**
The Page has a grid ( ingragistics grid, third party control) that makes a xmlhttprequest to the page itself to load some data on the fly. It sometimes work but mostly give a 404.

fidler also confrims the 404 error with the url & that url does exist and is correct.

I also verified the logs in IIS it confirm the 404 error. But not able to detect where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a request for more information:

I assume the page isn't POSTing to itself? Where is the POST coming from/how is it set up?

Have you tried using Fiddler or another tool to see if any other information is revealed? This should show you the exact path that leads to the 404 errors.
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: the page is posting to itself via POST xmlhttprequest. Updated more details in the main question. thanks.

Comment: Read the updated info. I'm afraid I don't have access to that control, so maybe their support forums have encountered this issue before. I'd imagine it should wire everything up for you automatically. If you can show them two requests, one that worked and one that didn't, that should help them narrow it down.